How does a pizza heat up in the oven?
Sometimes if you bake a frozen pizza (and are impatient) it can happen that the center of the pizza is still cold while the edges are already burning hot. How is this possible?

The thermal conductivity of the pizza is very low so comparatively little heat is transmitted to the centre compared with that transmitted to the outer layers.
Baked Alaska

We have a wood-fired pizza oven which we have been using for several years. The edges of the pizza always cook first. I suspect it is a combination of several factors. The edges present slightly more surface area, as they take-in heat on three faces, while the centre takes in heat from only two. More importantly, the edges take radiant heat from a neighbouring ring of the floor of the oven, while effectively shielding the centre of the pizza from that source of heat. Finally, the centre of the pizza is usually covered in toppings, which have a higher specific heat (they contain a lot of moisture) and shield the base of the pizza from the radiant heat of the roof of the oven.

Under the hypothesis of uniform pizza heating, the center requires more time to increase its temperature because usually contains ingredients with a higher specific heat than the edges.

"Under the hypothesis of uniform pizza heating" - a new sentence has just been invented.
